# Multiple Named Data Ranges into one dropdown list in Google Sheets

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have 2 named data ranges "NamedRange1" & "NamedRange2", each are on different sheets.
NamedRange1 data is collected when entered by the user and added to a drop down menu on another sheet. I would like to also add data that already exists in NamedRange2 to that drop down list. it works perfectly with one range but not with two with an error of invalid range.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Multiple named ranges just dont seem to be accepted .